# Can I use both RcppEigen and RcppArmadillo in my package?

Tags: r, rcpp

Following the instruction from the manual, I successfully using either one of them in my package. However, when I try to use both of them, I have the following warning:

```
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: replacing previous import by 'RcppEigen::fastLm' when loading 'simmen'
  Warning: replacing previous import by 'RcppEigen::fastLmPure' when loading 'simmen'
```

In my `DESCRIPTION` file, I have

```
Imports:
    Rcpp (>= 0.11.1),
    RcppArmadillo (>= 0.4.100.2.1),
    RcppEigen (>= 0.3.2.1.1)
```

I guess the warning is caused by `RcppArmadillo` and `RcppEigen` sharing the same name for `fastLm` and `fastLmPure`. Are there any methods to avoid the warning? For example, anything i can do in the `DESCRIPTION` file so that it wont load fastLm and `fastLmPure` from `RcppEigen` (or `RcppArmadillo`)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more judicious in your imports in your `NAMESPACE` file? Do you use `importFrom(…)`? If not, can you try using that?

Comment: That will do as will thinking about *why* you do this: You want the template headers of either. And those do _not_ conflict.  And most people get by with just one of the two, so it is not an issue we have cared about greatly.

Comment: Thanks, I am using `importFrom(...)` now. 
A quick question: If the package only need the header file from `Rcpp`, Shall I remove `Rcpp` from `Imports` and keep `Rcpp` in `LinkingTo` ?